# Itertools with conditions in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation, python-itertools, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to generate some vectors with numbers `[0....k-1]`, and with length k^n. n and k were given before.

```
k = 4
n = 2
args = list(product(range(k), repeat=n))
# vector=str([i for i in range(k)]*(n+1))
for i in product(range(k), repeat=k ** n):
    if (check(i, args)): print(i)
```

Commented line is not important,it was my idea. 
I need to generate this vectors with condition: I want to see each number from [0;k-1] in my vectors more or equal to (n) times. So it is task about permutations with replacements with special conditions to control numbers I can get. What shall I do?

For example I have k=2,n=2 vector from 4 elements and want to see `0` and `1` TWO or more times. 
I should get `0011 0101 0110 1001 1010 1100`

Everything is easy in example, but when k=5,n=2 (for example) there are 25-size vector and i want to see `0 1 2 3 4` 2 times and other 17 numbers should be from `0 1 2 3 4` it becomes difficult.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely. In your example, `k` is `2`, right?, You have `0` and `1` as elements.  And the vector length is `3`. But you also said that the vector length is `k^n`, so what is `n` here? And then, each element is supposed to appear at least `n + 1` times, and in the example that is `1`, so `n` is `0`? That still doesn't add up with the `k^n`...

Comment: sorry for bad example, just wanted to clarify task with n and k

Comment: Ah I see that's fine, but then for the real problem it would be, `k` elements, `k^n` vector length and at least `n + 1` repetitions of each element, right?

Comment: If this is exactly this problem can't you just get the binary representation of integers?

Comment: what are k and n in your example ?

Comment: I have edited, so it is more clear now.

Comment: Some specifications can help. Do you want exhaustive solutions? Can some random vectors passing the test be sufficient ?

Comment: the math target is checking all k-algebra functions (I have only 1 condition to decrease their number-it is meeting n times (minimal) each number)

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE:

Here is a solution that generates the necessary combinations only. It is in principle faster, although the complexity is still exponential and you can quickly hit the limits of recursion.

```
def my_vectors(k, n):
    # Minimum repetitions per element
    base_repetitions = [n] * k
    # "Unassigned" repetitions
    rest = k ** n - k * n
    # List reused for permutation construction
    permutation = [-1] * (k ** n)
    # For each possible repetition assignment
    for repetitions in make_repetitions(base_repetitions, rest):
        # Make all possible permutations
        yield from make_permutations(repetitions, permutation)

# Finds all possible repetition assignments
def make_repetitions(repetitions, rest, first=0):
    if rest <= 0:
        yield repetitions
    else:
        for i in range(first, len(repetitions)):
            repetitions[i] += 1
            yield from make_repetitions(repetitions, rest - 1, i)
            repetitions[i] -= 1

# Make all permutations with repetitions
def make_permutations(repetitions, permutation, idx=0):
    if idx >= len(permutation):
        yield list(permutation)
        # If you are going to use the permutation within a loop only
        # maybe you can avoid copying the list and do just:
        # yield permutation
    else:
        for elem in range(len(repetitions)):
            if repetitions[elem] > 0:
                repetitions[elem] -= 1
                permutation[idx] = elem
                yield from make_permutations(repetitions, permutation, idx + 1)
                repetitions[elem] += 1

for v in my_vectors(3, 2):
    print(v)
```

Output:

```
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2)
...
```

---

This is an inefficient but simple way to implement it:

```
from itertools import product
from collections import Counter

def my_vectors(k, n):
    for v in product(range(k), repeat=k ** n):
        count = Counter(v)
        if all(count[i] >= n for i in range(k)):
            yield v

for v in my_vectors(3, 2):
    print(v)
```

Output:

```
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2)
...
```

Obviously, as soon as your numbers get slightly bigger it will take forever to run, so it is only useful either for very small problems or as a baseline for comparison.

In any case, the number of items that the problem produces is exponentially large anyway, so although you can make it significantly better (i.e. generate only the right elements instead of all the possible ones and discarding), it cannot be "fast" for any size.

Comment: it is task for k-algebra functions and I need to generate very big values like k=20,n=2 etc. So, arent there more quick alghorhytm?

Comment: @СтаниславКитаев I am looking into it, just posted this as a baseline solution...

Comment: @СтаниславКитаев I have added another implementation that only generates the necessary elements. However, I'm afraid the numbers you suggest are just not realistic. For example, with `k = 20` and `n = 2`, vectors would have 400 elements. A possible repetition assignment is to have 20 repetitions of each element. Only for that case, you have on the order of 10⁵⁰⁰ possible permutations. And the number of possible repetition assignments is also combinatorial (partitions of the number 360 in 20 parts).

Comment: yeah,for k=20,n=2 its more then 20^14 (it is number of permutations ignoring our condition where we need 3 ONE and 3 ZERO) and 400 elements in each permutation. But il looks like polynomial and can be calculated with mapping I bet